# c cannot convert from type A* to type B*

Tags: c++

I need to change DMapEntry::pData from a char* to a class DMapData that contains the original pointer but still be able to refer to &pData[offset] in DMapEntry without changing it. Is this possible?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class DMapData {
    char* pData;
public:
    char* operator->() { return pData; }
    char operator[](size_t offset) { return pData[offset]; }
    friend class DMapEntry;
};

class DMapEntry {
    char* pStr;
public:
    DMapData pData;
/*----->*/    void getStr(size_t offset) { pStr = &pData[offset]; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DMapEntry a;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: If you make `operator[]` return a reference `char&` rather than a value `char` then you will be able to take the address of the result.

Comment: You want `pData` to be *what?*

Comment: sorry I really meant to include the & - just a typo

Comment: This is actually a C++ question, not C.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char& operator[](size_t offset) { return pData[offset]; }
```